# How to exclude properties from output CSV using LinqToCsv

Tags: c#

I'm using `LinqToCsv` to output a CSV file based on my below model.

```
[CsvColumn(Name = "Column_A", FieldIndex = 0)]
public string PropOne { get; set; }

[CsvColumn(Name = "Column_B", FieldIndex = 1)]
public bool PropTwo { get; set; }

[CsvColumn(Name = "Column_C", FieldIndex = 2)]
public bool PropThree { get; set; }

[CsvColumn(Name = "Column_D", FieldIndex = 3)]
public int PropFour { get; set; }

[CsvColumn(Name = "Column_E", FieldIndex = 4)]
public string PropFive { get; set; }

//I don't want the below to be output in my CSV
public int CommonId { get; set; }
public DifferentViewModel DifferentViewModel { get; set; }
```

To populate `PropFour` & `PropFive` I needed to introduce the `CommonId` and `DifferentViewModel` properties to the original model. The problem I have now is when I write the file it is including these two properties, even though I have not given them a field index.

I have tried setting:

```
IgnoreUnknownColumns = true
```

In the hope that perhaps as I had not decorated these properties, they might be classed as Unknown, however they are still outputted. Is there any way of excluding these properties from the output CSV short of creating a new model minus these properties and mapping to this model prior to the write.

**edit**

Some further readings shows me that

> "Fields and properties without FieldIndex get written last, in random
>   order."

which explains why these are still showing in my output CSV, and I also now understand that `IgnoreUnknownColumns` is for reading, not writing, so obviously would have no effect on my unwanted properties being added to my CSV.

But I still cant find anything in the documentation about excluding properties, it looks like I'm going to have to split this model, one for setting up and one for the actual write.

Comment: isn't there a select function?

Comment: Taking a quick peek at the codebase, IgnoreUnknownColumns appears to pertain reading from the file, not writing to it.  The code doesn't seem to include any way of excluding fields or properties of an object.  But, it's relatively easy stuff.  All you'd need to do is add a boolean `Ignore` property to the CsvColum attribute, then add a line or two of code to check for it here https://github.com/mperdeck/LINQtoCSV/blob/e29c48f071697583a4a77c361912875c19440fb2/LINQtoCSV/FieldMapper.cs then send the OP a pull request.  And that's open source for ya.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cloned the project from git and inspected the code more closely as it was my intention to add an **ignore** attribute as suggested by Will.

After locating the `WriteObject` method within `FieldMapper.cs` I noticed that the library was actually already doing what I wanted:

```
if (m_fileDescription.EnforceCsvColumnAttribute &&
(!tfi.hasColumnAttribute))
{
   continue;
}
```

So by setting this to true when instantiating a new `CsvFileDescription` like this:

```
CsvFileDescription outputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
{
   SeparatorChar = ',', // comma delimited
   FirstLineHasColumnNames = true, // column names in first record
   FileCultureName = "en-GB", // use formats used in the UK
   EnforceCsvColumnAttribute = true // don't output if there is no csv column attribute                
};
```

The output would no longer contain the undesired columns as these properties did not contain the `[CsvColumn]` attribute in my model.

For more information [click here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library#EnforceCsvColumnAttribute). Unsure why I failed to spot this existing functionality but here it is for anyone else's benefit.